# How to disable menu from appearing when scrolling up with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am using a external theme for a project, but I am not very strong in front-end.

It uses this JavaScript for hiding the header on scroll:

```
function HideShowHeader() {

        var didScroll;
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var delta = 80;
        var navbarHeight = 0;
        var navbarHideAfter = navbarHeight

        $(window).scroll(function(event){
            didScroll = true;
        });         

        if( $('.scroll-hide').length > 0 ){

            setInterval(function() {
                if (didScroll) {
                    hasScrolled();
                    didScroll = false;
                }
            }, 100);

        }

        return false;

        function hasScrolled() {
            var st = $(this).scrollTop();

            if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
                return;

            if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHideAfter){
                if( $('.scroll-hide').length > 0 ){
                $('header').addClass('nav-hide');
                }
            } else {
                if( $('.scroll-hide').length > 0 ){
                if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                    $('header').removeClass('nav-hide');
                }
                }
            }

            lastScrollTop = st;
        }


}//End Hide Show Header
```

But right now the header re-appears when I scroll up. I don't want this. I just want the header to dissapear when scrolling down, and appear again when you scrolled back all the way to the top. Not just in the middle of a webpage.

How can I modify this code to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide your header via adding hide class when scroll and middle of the page and remove hide class when you back to top. Below is code :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 100) 
   $("header").addClass("hide");
   else 
   $("header").removeClass("hide");
  $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll >= 100) 
       $("header").addClass("hide");
   else 
       $("header").removeClass("hide");
  });
 });
 /*Here 100 is in px, set in px from where you want to hide your header.*/
```

Comment: By the way: jQuery provides a **hide()** function. So just in case the "hide" class only sets display to none, use jQuery function. It also provides the functionality of animating the fadeout.

Comment: Yes, you are right but it depends on developer whether s/he want to give animation or just hide.Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px;margin-top:30px;">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to hide a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
  <p>Scroll up to show the navbar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script>
var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
window.onscroll = function() {
var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
  if (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
  prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```